# Identify $f$ using Taylor coefficients of $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an analytic function defined in the unit disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| <1 \}$ where for any $n >0$ we have:

$$\left|f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| \leq e^{-n}$$

Find $f$

I know this can be solved using Taylor coefficients of $f$ as that suggested in the practice textbook problem. However, I cannot figure how to find $f$.

Does someone know how to solve this or have a link to a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Further hint: if the first nonzero Taylor coefficient of $f$ at $0$ is $c_k$, what does that tell you about
$\displaystyle\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(z)}{z^k}\ ?$